# What is the best method to handle lots of input variables for a program in Python?

Tags: python, input

I am developing a scientific package to model a biological system and I'm using Python for this reason. My program has be initialized with a lot of input data and variables. After some research, I decided to use JSON as an input file which in my implementation both contains data and variables.

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or not? What I do is to read a JSON file and put it into a Python dictionary. Then, in the `__init__` of the class, I declare lots of variables with the same names that they have in the dictionary. For instance, if I have an item in JSON like `params` then I declare a variable like `self.params = json["params"]`.

Now, I was wondering if I should do this or I can just declare one big dictionary in initialization like `self.options = json` and then use this in the class. If I do this, first of all my code will be really ugly; second, Python has to access big chunk of data every time that I wanted to read one variable from `self.options` which might not be as efficient as having class variable. Is it?

Beside this method that I described, what are the other way to handle lots of input parameters to a program?

Comment: Accessing values from a dictionary by key is very efficient, so that's not a major worry. If you want specific instance methods to access certain subsets of the `params`, you could define them e.g. `def some_method(self, a, b, **args):` and call them `self.some_method(**self.params)`.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, but what if I wanted to change some variables in the dictionary frequently. Is it still good idea to use dictionary then?

Comment: Attributes are stored in a dictionary (called `__dict__`) anyway, I would expect no difference in performance. *"Python has to access big chunk of data every time that I wanted to read one variable from `self.options`"* - this isn't true, dictionary values are accessed by hashing the keys, which is very fast; see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68

Comment: Yes, Python dictionaries are really, really fast, particularly if you're just checking to see if a key is in one, or getting a value by its key (you don't have to iterate over the whole thing to do that, nor does the computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your configuration options seem to be rather complex, it seems to be a good idea to provide a separate and dedicated class for handling the configuration. This moves all the code that requires knowledge about the structure of the configuration file into this class, and keeps it out of the rest of the application.

You can then set `self.options` to an instance of this class and use its methods and attributes to access your options. This not only allows you to write `self.options.foo.bar` instead of `self.options["foo"]["bar"]`, but also to provide actual access methods that calculate derived options from whatever is in your config file. It's difficult to give an example without knowing what kind of options you are using.

To do this, you can either load the JSON structure and pass it to your class for initialization, or you can use the `object_hook` argument to `json.load` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)) to create custom classes, allowing you to read the JSON info as whatever class structure you want.

As an example (and this is rather dirty, you might want a cleaner version for production code):

```
class Bag(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return self[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError 


>>> import json
>>> x = json.loads('{"foo": {"bar": 23}}', object_hook=Bag)
>>> x.foo.bar
23
```

Using the `ConfigParser` module instead of JSON would make the config file a bit more readable to humans, but the idea of creating a custom config class to provide easier access remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good idea. I like the ability to preprocess data for further use in the class.

Answer (score 2):

> Beside this method that I described, what are the other way to handle lots of input parameters to a program?

*My* preferred way to handle large input parameters is to use the [configparser module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

One key advantage for me is that you can have some kind of "configuration in layers". That is, providing a `default.ini` config file with "sane defaults". And letting custom config file override those default values for specific usages and/or various sites.